# Esqueleto query that returns constant value

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

Is it possible to use [esqueleto](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.4.3) to create a query that returns a constant value? Like `SELECT 1` for example.

Comment: Try `select (return 1)` -- can't check it now, but it might work.

Comment: @chi: unfortunately not: `No instance for (Database.Esqueleto.Internal.Sql.SqlSelect Int r0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import Database.Esqueleto

-- | We have to specialize `val` or else the type inferencer
-- will complain about the `Esqueleto` instance.
val_ :: Int -> SqlExpr (Value Int)
val_ = val

query :: SqlPersistT IO [Value Int]
query = select $ return (val_ 1)
```

@chi's comment was close, but the `1` needed to be lifted into a `SqlExpr`. `val` is written generically and depends on an `Esqueleto` class instance. Normally the type inferencer would grab this as soon as you used `from` and pulled in a SQL table, but since none of that is available here we have to specialize manually.

Overall a good example of how typeclasses can obfuscate meaning and force people to turn to documentation or forums.